# How does Windows know I'm installing something?

Tags: windows, windows-installer, installation, uac

It's a common practice to disallow users from installing programs without elevated privileges, especially in larger companies. When the user runs the installation executable (whether `.exe` or `.msi`), the user is prompted for these admin credentials before User Access Control will allow the installation. A lot of programs that require installation take advantage of the default Windows installer `.msi` packaging or something similar, but an executable file could perform all the same functionalities, right?

Is it this common installation-packaging solution that tells Windows, "Hey, I'm an installer. Something is being installed."? Windows isn't analyzing the actual behavior of the executable file, right?

Comment: Modern applications (including third-party installers) are expected to contain an entry in the manifest saying whether or not elevation is needed.  For older applications, Windows attempts to guess.  I don't know to what extent the expected behaviour of the executable is analysed, since the algorithm has never been fully documented AFAIK.  However, we do know that the guess is made before the executable actually starts running.

Comment: I'm not certain how this works for MSI files.  Windows Installer can elevate dynamically though (i.e., during the installation) so perhaps it simply waits and only requests elevation if it is asked to do something that requires it.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Yeah, I  was wondering about that. It seems that for the `.exe` installers, Windows asks for elevation before anything happens, but most `.msi` files don't ask until it's performing a step that actually needs it. I don't believe that _all_ executable files require elevation on my system, though, just the handful of `.exe` installers I've had to use.

Comment: "modern" (that term still makes me chuckle in disbelief) "apps" and their installers tend to be installed per user and not require any elevated permissions.  I'll use the term "mature" applications and installers can be per-user or per-machine but tend to be per-machine and tend to require elevation as a result.  This story in MSI is very well documented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of an .MSI, sure, Windows automatically knows your installing something. I think your question is more along the lines of what about anything other then an .MSI?   Windows has some heuristics built in that AFAIK are managed by the application compatibility team.  They do things to detect what they is a setup (like file name, process name, inspection of the summary information stream and so on ) and perform various functions such as detecting a possible failed install, asking if it was an install and if it failed and them performing application compatibility shims such as version lying and forced UAC elevation prompting.

You get to avoid this ugly world my authoring properly designed MSIs. :)

Comment: That makes sense, all `.msi`s are installers, right? But as Harry was saying in the question's comments, some `.msi`s don't ask for credentials until they reach a certain step, so those seem to have a dynamic elevation process. Heuristics for `.exe`s would make a lot of sense too, but is it a foolproof system? Wouldn't someone with malicious intent still be able to write something that could "install" without triggering the UAC?

Comment: It's not a foolproof system for EXEs. They are merely shims to try to help it work not really a security model per say.  MSI has a robust security model that is very well documented and would take a chapter to describe it.

Comment: So `.msi`s are not only for convenience of application deployment and compatibility, but also for security?

Comment: Yes. MSI has a security model where administrators can set policies as what can and can't be installed / patched and delegation can be made to the user to start the process while not exposing those permissions to the user because the work is done by a backend service running as SYSTEM.

Comment: So final question, methinks: what I'm hearing is that the `.msi` has a ton of great security features that are very well-documented, however, it is the responsibility of the application's publisher to actually make use of these features. If one so desired, they could ignore all these recommended practices and create a potentially dangerous "installer" that Windows would have a hard time detecting, right? (I sound kind of shady, don't I? =/)

Comment: I think the worst a publisher could do is 1) create a poorly written installer that doesn't follow the model and has a suboptimal user/administrator experience 2) open the model up to man in the middle attacks  3) Instruct MSI to make baseline changes to the O/S that result in a less secure machine.

Comment: Note that only old (or improperly built) executables are subject to heuristics.  If the executable contains a manifest, the manifest tells Windows whether or not elevation is required.  Windows does not attempt to second-guess this.

Answer (score 2):

If your question is about asking for admin credentials, that's normal behavior when an executeable has a manifest that says it requires admin privilieges. I guess that if you say your InnoSetup requires admin privileges it will include a manifest requiring elevation, and Windows will show the elevation prompt.

There is no such thing as Windows InstallShield, in case you are thinking that InstallShield is a Microsoft Windows product. InstallShield is a 3rd party product that in many cases creates an MSI file. MSI files are marked (when built) as to whether they require elevation or not. It's the summary information strean Word Count that says whether the MSI requires elevation to install or not:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372870(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: My mistake with the "InstallShield" bit, I was getting it confused with UAC for some reason. Question Updated. So it's really up to the publisher to note whether or not the installer requires elevation? Surely there must be some analysis that Windows does, otherwise one could simply _not_ include this manifest and this would seem like a little bit of a security hole. Or could one just write an executable that would perform all the same steps that an `.msi` or manifest'd `.exe` would and fly under the UAC's radar?

Comment: Technically there are some interesting InstallShield shims distributed by Windows. :)   They intercept the InstallScript engine and substitute a different version provided by Flexera to Microsoft for appcompat reasons.

Comment: @iAmMortos: there's no security issue here.  If you are logged in as a standard user and run an installer, then either Windows will demand an admin password or it will run the installer without admin privilege.  Standard users are allowed to install software, provided the installation only affects the user's own account.

Comment: (If the system administrator wants to prevent users from installing or running any unapproved software, a different approach is needed.  Group Policy can be used to whitelist approved executables and configure Windows to refuse to run any executables not on the whitelist.)

Answer (score 0):

MSIs can be authored per-user or per-machine. Per-user installs won't ask for elevation by default. Per-machine installs will ask for elevation once they hit the InstallExecuteSequence.